# Add a beforeSend loading to this script

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I need someone to help me with this script. It is an infinite scroll (pagination in Laravel). The script works perfectly, the only thing I don't know is how to add a Loading below while looking for the next page. It would be something like this:

```
beforeSend: function(){        
  $('.ajax-load').show();
}
```

But I can't figure out how to do it because I'm very new to JS.

Here is my entire code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $(window).scroll(fetchCondolences);
                var searching = false;

                function fetchCondolences(){
                    
                    if (!searching) { 
                        searching = true;
                        var page = $('.endless-pagination').data('next-page'); 
                        if(page !== null){
                            clearTimeout( $.data( this, "scrollCheck"));
                            $.data( this, "scrollCheck", setTimeout(function(){
                                var scroll_position_for_condolences_load = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() + 100;
                                searching = false;
                                
                                if(scroll_position_for_condolences_load >= $(document).height()) {
                                    
                                    
                                    $.get(page, function(data){                                        
                                        $('.condolences').append(data.condolences);
                                        $('.endless-pagination').data('next-page', data.next_page);
                                    });
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                } 
                            }, 350)
                            .done(function(data){    
        
                                $('.ajax-load').hide();
                                
                            }))
                        } else{
                            $('.ajax-load').show();
                            $('.ajax-load').html("<center>"+ trans_No_more_records_found +"</center>");
                        }              
                    }
                } 
            });
```

```
<section class="condolences endless-pagination pt-4" data-next-page="{{$condolences->nextPageUrl()}}">            
            @include('dead.extras.scroll_condolences')  
        </section>

        <div class="py-4">
            <div class="ajax-load rounded-md hidden w-full py-4 bg-gray-100">
                <center>
                    <p>{{__('Load more')}}... <img class="inline" width="50px" height="50px" src="https://i.gyazo.com/b1821cac720bfa56367e6a23972659ed.gif"></p>
                </center>
            </div>            
        </div>
        <script>var trans_No_more_records_found = "{{__('No more records found')}}";</script>
```

I appreciate any help. Thank you

I need someone to help me add a loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add loading once the code reaches if statement to check scroll position and clear loading when data is appended.

```
if(scroll_position_for_condolences_load >= $(document).height()) {
  $('.ajax-load').show(); // Show loader
  $.get(page, function(data){
    $('.ajax-load').hide(); // hide loader
    $('.condolences').append(data.condolences);    
    $('.endless-pagination').data('next-page', data.next_page);
  });
}
```